# Webpack generated library has problem being imported by project where useBuiltIns is set to 'usage'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, babeljs

I want to write a reusable UI component library and pack it with Webpack. However, when I import it in another project, where the babelrc has `useBuiltIns: 'usage'` set, the import will fail with an error:

```
"export 'default' (imported as 'Component') was not found in 'component'
```

This is part of my webpack configuration in library project:

```
output: {
  path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), './dist'),
  filename: 'component.js',
  chunkFilename: '[id].js',
  library: 'Component',
  libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
  libraryExport: 'default'
},

...

module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel-loader'
    },
```

Babel configuration in library project:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      "env",
      {
        modules: false,
        targets: {
          "browsers": ["> 1%", "last 2 versions", "not ie <= 8"]
        }
      }
    ],
    "stage-2"
  ]
}
```

Babel configuration in the consuming project:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/app'
  ]
}
```

Where the `useBuiltIns: 'usage'` is implicitly set.

While the problem could be solve by either set `useBuiltIns: false` or `scriptType: 'unambiguous'` in the consuming project. But this is not what I want. Since my goal is to provide a reusable library and it is expected to be used in different projects. I cannot force all the consuming projects to do this.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer in the Vue.js forum: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/export-default-imported-as-components-was-not-found-in-mylib/63905

The problem was that I was adding the dependency with a local path, namely:

```
$ npm install ../component
```

And in this case, npm is creating a symlink in `node_modules`. It seems that some babel plugin doesn't really like symlinks.

After I've changed to use git:

```
$ npm install git+file://localhost/path/to/component
```

Everything works fine.